# Ajax jabber/XMPP client recommendations (real experience only please) !

Tags: ajax, xmpp, ejabberd, chatroom

i'm setting up a chat system for my niche social site and have decided on ejabberd for the server side, but i cannot find any decent web-based ajax clients. most seem to be abandoned years ago or simply do not work. i've looked at every single one here :

http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/

Is anyone running a live site and using an ajax-based client that they can vouch for that works and is in active development ? I do not mind paying for something, but I do not want to do any development work whatsoever.

thanks in advance.

Comment: stanza is also a good option. refer https://github.com/legastero/stanza.io

Answer (score 16):

I'm unsure of its maintainership status, but I usually point people who ask me this question to [TrophyIM](http://code.google.com/p/trophyim/). It is a small and themeable chat client written on top of [Strophe.js](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe).

If you want group chat, you can try [Speeqe](http://code.stanziq.com/speeqe) (see it in action [here](http://speeqe.com)), which is also based on Strophe.js.

Most people have very specific needs in the web domain, and I think this contributes to the lack of generally useful web-based IM clients. You can easily write one yourself, and there are several examples of such systems in my book, *[Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery](http://professionalxmpp.com)*.

*Disclaimer: I wrote Strophe.js and the book so I am obviously biased.*

Comment: IMHO, the answer is still true till now, 2013, three years later.

Answer (score 7):

We just released [Candy](http://candy-chat.github.io/candy/) under MIT-License, an AJAX Jabber Client built with Strophe.js.

**Why Candy?**

- Focused on real-time multi-user chatting
- Easy to configure, easy to run, easy to use
- Highly customizable
- 100% well-documented JavaScript source code
- Built for Jabber (XMPP), using famous technologies
- Used and approved in a productive environment with up to 400
  concurrent users
- Works with all major web browsers including IE7

Take a look :)

Comment: Candy is of course awesome and looks to be among the current cream of the crop. I'm looking for something that would let me show multiple twitter-like streams horizontally, TweetDeck style, with access control and file uploads. I wonder whether rolling up the JS sleeves and jumping on candy-plugins bandwagon would be the way to go here.

Comment: It's not a library, it's a client. If you'd like to use it as an im-client you'll need to make some non-trivial changes. I think there are better options for normal im-clients and/or using strophe.js directly.

Comment: @DitherSky thanks for changing the link, we changed the organization name some time ago and I forgot to update it here.

Comment: Well we thought some time ago about adding also classical IM support to it but our spare time is rare currently..

Answer (score 3):

If you are ready to go ahead and build out custom UI for your chat application + doing some PHP/Javascript/XMPP stuff you may checkout [Jaxl library](http://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL). It have several examples on how to build a web based client for real-time chat.

Alternately you can simply try out ready to use chat client from [Jaxl IM](http://jaxl.im) which is a generic/scalable client written using Jaxl library.

Comment: Thanks i've already signedup with them, but they're still in alpha with beta coming out beginning of the year.

Comment: Jaxl IM is down. Is there any way to get the said client? Is it open-source?

Comment: Jaxl IM is no longer an active project. It was shutdown some 10 months back. Kindly use other alternatives available in the market.

Answer (score 3):

I played with strophe.js a lot in the past. It is a really cool library for writting xmpp clients(**pure javascript**). In his book [professional xmpp](http://professionalxmpp.com/) he explains how to write a multi-user-chat client in javascript. I guess you have to do some coding, but this library is really powerfull and you have complete control.

Answer (score 1):

Another one that's doing rather well is [Jappix](https://www.jappix.com) which is open sourced here https://github.com/jappix. With an overview of the different sub-projects here http://jappix.org/features

Depending on your needs Jappix Mini may be all you need. (Facebook like bottom-right chat widget) Otherwise you could get a copy of the full client running.

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

[SparkWeb](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/sparkweb/index.jsp) is a decent web based XMPP client. I understand question is quite old, thought of sharing the information, may be someone might find this helpful

Answer (score 0):

I use iJab. It's small, simple, fast, Facebook look and feel. http://code.google.com/p/ijab/